# Rails Nokogiri gem - scrape data using itemprop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have a div which looks like as following and I am trying to scrape the data using `itemprop` but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
 <div class="information">
    <h1 itemprop="title">Some title here</h1>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">St. Inigoes</span>,    
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">MD</span>
    <span itemprop="addressCountry">US</span>
 </div>
```

Without itemprop I can get the data uaing `data.css('.information').css('h1').try(:text)` but if i try the following i get null `data.css('meta[@itemprop="title"]')` and the response I get it null.

So my question is how can i scrape the data of all `span` and `h1` using `itemprop`

Comment: Take the `@` out for css, that's for xpath only. Also it's a h1 not a meta. Maybe just: `data.at('[itemprop=title]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to scrape using the following technique

```
title = data.at("//h1[@itemprop = 'title']").children.text
addressLocality = data.at("//span[@itemprop = 'addressLocality']").children.text
addressRegion = data.at("//span[@itemprop = 'addressRegion']").children.text
addressCountry = data.at("//span[@itemprop = 'addressCountry']").children.text
```